# 100% cpu because of this thread java

Tags: java

i have just attempted to add something to my game where if one player is hit by a bullet his health goes down. problem is when i am checking for this, CPU is at 100% and everything sooo laggy. This is a problem. here is the thread i am using:

```
 package Graphics;

 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;


 public class BulletCollision implements Runnable {
     Player1 player1 = new Player1();
     Player2 player2 = new Player2();

     public Thread checkBulletCollision = new Thread(this);

     public void checkPlayerBulletCollide() {
         if (player2.getBulletX() > player1.getX() && 
             player2.getBulletX() < player1.getX() - 50) {
            player2.decHealth(50);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         while(true) {
             checkPlayerBulletCollide();
             try {
                 checkBulletCollision.sleep(100);
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(BulletCollision.class.getName()).log(
                     Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

i am pretty sure this is where the problem is. there are no errors when compiled or ran. if anyone could help that would be amazing! and i just make this class so the code is not perfect. i have tried a lot to fix this, the Threads start() method is being called in my Display class which only displays the JFrame. i previously had the start method in one of my player classed.

Comment: if you need more details like my hierarchy of classes where all the methods, int's etc are from just ask. but i thought it would be not necersary

Comment: Did you try to use a profiler?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using this block free running in a separate thread is not correct in this case.

```
while(true) {
    checkPlayerBulletCollide();
    try {
        checkBulletCollision.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BulletCollision.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I'd only do this once each frame, I'd call the `checkPlayerBulletCollide()` from the drawing logic.

Also note that `Thread.sleep()` is a static function, so you can't make a specific Thread instance sleep from another Thread, a Threac can just put itself to sleep...

**EDIT** If you would like to code nice and clean (which is very good), I'd advise using the locking mechanisms we have from Java 1.5 on.

Even though this is (in the current context of 2 users with 1 bullet each) not lightweight ebough, I'd use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). The checking thread would have to issue a queue.take(), but the actual Integer value wouldn't matter (later on e.g. with more bullets or players, you could put objects in the queue that specify which bullets and which users to check...). The drawing logic - or the logic controlling the drawing would do queue.offer(0). The checking Thread would look like this:

```
public class BulletCollision implements Runnable{

    Player1 player1 = new Player1();
    Player2 player2 = new Player2();

    public BlockingQueue<Integer> checkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
    public void checkPlayerBulletCollide() {
        if(player2.getBulletX() > player1.getX() && player2.getBulletX() < player1.getX() -50) {
            player2.decHealth(50);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                queue.take();
                checkPlayerBulletCollide();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BulletCollision.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                break; //I'd put this here. If we were interrupted, the hread should stop gracefully.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when you're done with drawing a frame, you should issue a `queue.offer(0);`

Comment: No, the drawing is NOT the logic. Isolate animation into a model and the drawing must be drawing only.

Comment: @Aubin I understand your efforts on separating the business logic from the visuals - that is good. But sometimes performance requirements force us to use less than clear solutions (denormalization of DB tables to name one). I'll update my answer with something better.

Comment: do you mean just use the method without a new thread? because either way it takes 100% cpu

Comment: @user1776707 The bottleneck could also be somewhere else.. if you can pastebin some code here.. I can have a look later.

Comment: can you help me with anouther issue?

Comment: [SO] is big. We will help you with whatever you have on your mind, given that it conforms to the [corresponding part of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). If it is a different problem, consider posting it in a new question, so that every [SO] member can see it. There are way more experienced people here than I myself am...

Comment: can you help me with how to get the value of bulletX? in the above code bullet x is protected int bulletX and player2 extends the class that has the int. but from the class above the value of bulletX is always 0? why is this? i commented that below, and it works if i change protected int bulletX to protected static int bulletX but the if both players bullets are shot at the same time both bullets freez, probly because of it being static

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in this code.  There are one or two flaws, but nothing in this code that would result in laggyness ... as far as I can tell.

---

FWIW, the flaws are as follows:

1) This is bad style:

```
  checkBulletCollision.sleep(100);
```

The `Thread.sleep` method is static, so you should invoke it as:

```
  Thread.sleep(100);
```

2) Your thread `run()` method should return if it receives an interrupt.  You have coded it to keep going ... which would defeat the purpose of interrupting it.

Comment: can you help me with how to get the value of bulletX? in the above code bullet x is protected int bulletX and player2 extends the class that has the int. but from the class above the value of bulletX is always 0? why is this?